# How to add a view in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, view

I am quite new to rails but i have searched a lot how to do this but it doesnt seem to work for me. Im trying to create a new view called request for my model called steppy_steps, so i created a new file in the views directory called request.html.rb, added this to my routes, `match '/request' => 'pages#request',` also tried get "steppy_tests/home", and lastly added (def request, end), to my `Steppy_Tests_Controller.rb` but when i check the url it gives me an `error:Couldn't find SteppyTest with id=home`

I cant figure out what to do any help would be great! Thanks in advance.

Comment: just add view file 'views/view_name/new.erb' etc

Comment: i created a file in 'views/steppy_steps/request.html.erb' but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: do you have a proper handler for an action?

Comment: Writing answer for you

Comment: thats what I thought i was doing in steppy_tests_controller.rb, but judging by your comment thats not it right?

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on the [MVC programming pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (which is what Rails is based on)

In order to make a `view`, you need to have the `controller` and `model` aspects in place too. I think you're doing this already, but to help you understand more, I'll outline below:

---

**Views : Controller Actions**

If you want to show a view from the `steppy_steps` controller, you need to first have a controller action set up to handle the request. You'd normally use a self-named controller for this (controller name `steppy_steps`), and have various actions for that

In your routes, you'll then "capture" the request to your `steppy_steps` controller like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :steppy_steps
```

This will create a set of [RESTful routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default), which you can then translate into your controller, like this:

```
#app/controllers/steppy_steps_controller.rb
def index
   #Index code
end

def show
   #Show code
end
```

This will allow you to create a `views` directory which can contain the views for `/views/steppy_steps/show.html.erb` and `/views/steppy_steps/index.html.erb`

---

**Routes Are Super Important**

The error you're getting is caused by you sending `/home` to your view

The problem here is that if you're using a route which has an in-built `id` param (the `show` action routes have this), then Rails will look for the extra params after the URL

To fix this, you'll have to provide more of your code, but I also believe you'd be better understanding the fundamentals of Rails a little more

---

**Adding Routes**

You can add routes & views as you wish

If you're looking to add a `requests` route / view, I'd do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :steppy_steps do
  collection do
    get :requests
  end
end
```

This will allow you to create `/steppy_steps/requests`

Comment: thanks this helps a lot! sorry i understood i didnt provide enough information, i am working with a scaffold i created, so it already has the basic files it supposed to create, like show new etc, im just trying to add an extra vie to this called requests

Comment: thanks a lot! i also just found out a command to let me create it as well:rails g controller controllername new create

Comment: sorry, now i have successfully created a new view,but now i cannot reference my variable from it with out getting an error, for instance using the same code as in new or show gives me error : undefined method `goal' for nil:NilClass. im assuming i have to define this connection somewhere?